# Will changing the server time on a MySQL server (v 5.0) have any impact on the SQL Server?

Tags: linux, mysql

I am dealing with a production system that has the time set as June 2009 .
Will fixing this time to the current date break anything while the SQL Server is running?  will there be any issues restarting the service?
Version of the SQL Server is v 5.0.77  running a mix of innodb and myisam.
There is no replication involved.

update, when I say 'break something" I meant in the SQL server process/Daemon itself.  not applications querying the server, not backups configured, not replication, not server monitoring services, not license issues, not anything other than the MySQL process and the way it deals with 6 year time changes while the server is running.

update 2: Maybe I should rephrase the question.  Can mysql break due to a date change? I still don't understand why this is being down voted.

Comment: The only way to know is test.

Comment: I don't understand why telling you to test this has got you so riled up. Even if any of us have some experience with a similar scenario there's no guarantee that it would apply to your specific scenario. In that case, telling you to test it is wise and prudent guidance.

Comment: The other posters are right. You should test this yourself. Doing so is a trivial task, and you will have first-hand proof of whether or not things break instead of relying on some internet rando's take on a half-explained situation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*MySQL does not care what time it is, in general.* You can stop the daemon, set the clock, and start the daemon with essentially no ill effects. Technically this could break TLS but the date is already horribly wrong and so TLS can't really be set up in any reasonable way now.

What you're likely to break is your application. MySQL will use your system clock to timestamp data in tables (if you ask it to) and anything comparing `NOW` to hours/days/months ago will break horribly, causing untold pain and data cleanup. You need to set up a test environment to see what the effect is on your application. This is not a change you run without being sure of the consequences on your application.

Answer (score 3):

We have no knowledge of your application. The only way for you to be sure is for you to test it.

Spin up some VMs and do appropriate configuration/testing.

Comment: I am only concerned about the server itself not application.  Once I get the go-ahead the applications are safe to have the date changed, I need to be sure the mysql server/daemon itself is OK with such a huge date change.  also, why is this being downvoted?

Comment: We have no knowledge of your configuration.Spin up a VM and test it,.. There is a bit of a theme going one here.

Comment: what "configuration" are you referring to?  what time-change sensitive configuration in MySQL v5 is there?   again, I am not talking about backups, applications, queries, connecting to the server, etc.. just the mysql daemon itself, running myisam and innodb.

Comment: The (unknown) configuration of _your_ server and the application it runs. Only you can set that up and run appropriate tests. I guess you don't get it. **Only you can test whether making a six and a half year time change will affect your server and the applications it runs.** What happens if someone here says yeah no worries it'll be ok and then your app crashes ?

Comment: application is not my problem. let's pretend there is no applications running or querying the server.  Can mysql break due to a date change?

Comment: If you are going to make a 6.5 year time change it absolutely is your problem.

Comment: In this case, "the application" includes MySQL.  So, you should spin up a VM, set the time to 2009, start MySQL, change the time, and then check to make sure MySQL is still running as you need it to.  Nobody here with any sense is going to give you the absolute go-ahead to do this, because there's always the risk of something you haven't mentioned making the assumptions behind the answer invalid, and thus invalidating the answer.